# Bit-string without consecutive 1's, using Top-down DP

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, bitstring

[count all distinct binary strings without two consecutive 1's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-binary-strings-without-consecutive-1s/)

I tried to convert bottom-to-top dynamic programming approach(*mentioned in the link*) to recursive relation but could not able to get the correct output.

```
#include<iostream>
#define n 4
using namespace std;


int bitstring(int N, int b = 0)
{
    static int s = 0;
    //termination condition
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    if(b == 1)
    {
        s += bitstring(N - 1, 0);
    }
    if (b == 0)
    {
        s = bitstring(N - 1, 0) + bitstring(N - 1, 1);
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << bitstring(n) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

for N = 3
output is **5**

illustration for N=3

```
                f(3,0)        f(3,1)
                /     \          |
            f(2,0)  f(2,1)     f(2,0)
            /   \      |       /     \
        f(1,0) f(1,1) f(1,1)  f(1,0)  f(1,1)
          |      |       |      |        |
          1      1       1      1        1
```

Comment: For one, the order of function calls in `s = bitstring(N - 1, 0) + bitstring(N - 1, 1)` is unspecified, so _either_ recursive call could be made first.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, always `bitstring(N-1,0)` executed first, after that only call to `bitstring(N-1,1)` is made. I have checked the same on the debugger.

Comment: You may have the correct order this time, but a different compiler (or different optimization settings) can cause the order to change.  Another problem is the assignment to the static `s` variable (think about it).

Answer (score 0):

At least for case `N==1` you have two sequences [0] and [1].
May be it is better to start from corner cases ^_^
And for case `b==1` and `b==0` you are using different manipulations with `s`, is it should be like that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.